# Auxiliary function Grade calculator

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Why am I being told the let is unfinished?

```
 let comp_grade (perc_exam, perc_homework, perc_attendance) = let (grade_exam, grade_homework, grade_attendance) =
    (float)(perc_exam / 100 * grade_exam + perc_homework / 100 * grade_homework + perc_attendance / 100 * grade_attendance);

let COP4555_grade_computer = comp_grade(50,30,20);
let CEN3723_grade_computer = comp_grade(70,30,0);

let COP4555_student1_grade = COP4555_grade_computer (90, 95, 100);
let COP4555_student2_grade = COP4555_grade_computer (70, 80, 100);
let CEN3723_student1_grade = COP4555_grade_computer (90, 95, 100);
let CEN3723_student2_grade = COP4555_grade_computer (70, 80, 100);
```

Edit: Individually they work, but when I put them together the inner function now says it is unfinished.

Comment: which one us unfinished?

Comment: the " let (grade_exam, grade_homework, grade_attendance) ="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let comp_grade ( perc_exam,  perc_homework, perc_attendance) 
               (grade_exam, grade_homework, grade_attendance) =
     float (perc_exam       / 100 * grade_exam + 
            perc_homework   / 100 * grade_homework + 
            perc_attendance / 100 * grade_attendance)
```

Return an function

```
let comp_grade ( perc_exam,  perc_homework,  perc_attendance) = 
           fun (grade_exam, grade_homework, grade_attendance) ->
     float (perc_exam       / 100 * grade_exam + 
            perc_homework   / 100 * grade_homework + 
            perc_attendance / 100 * grade_attendance)
```

Comment: is there a way that i can make the first function return an inner function which has 3 parameters?